# How to write a parallel version for a function in R

Tags: r, function, parallel.foreach

I have to write a parallel version for the following **function**:

```
result = rep(NA, 500000)
index = 1
for(i in 1:10){
for(j in rnorm(10)){
for(k in runif(5, 10, 90)){
result[index] = i * j * k
index = index + 1
print(index)
}
}
}
```

If I type index, I get 501. For results, I get 499'500 NA's.

```
NA's  
499500
```

I did the following:

```
result = rep(NA, 50000)
index = 1

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i=1:10, j = rnorm(5, 10, 90), k =runif(5, 10, 90)) %dopar% {
  result[index] = i * j * k
  index = index + 1
}
```

However, this is not correct. If I type index, I get 1. For results, I get no NA's.

Do you have any suggestions on **how to change the parallel code so that I get the same values as in the first code?**

Comment: Why not look at the results?

Comment: @IRTFM In the firs version, I get 501. In the parallel version I get 1.

Comment: I think you probably want `%do%` rather than `%dopar%`. Look at the `?foreach` help page.

Comment: There's randomness in your code that you shouldn't expect results to be the same without setting a seed. But keeping track of a seed and getting things done in the same order across processors will not be easy. I would suggest pre-drawing all the random numbers before the loops if you need to get the same results either way.

Comment: (Also, I hope this is an illustrative example, otherwise there's no sense in parallelizing such a trivially vectorizable operation. You'd get more speed up writing a vectorized version.)